# Using .slideToggle with dynamically generated divs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, slidetoggle

I have divs created within a while loop displaying a MySQL query.  I'd like to hide and show them with .slideToggle.  I can't use one class as that would trigger every specific div on the page to slide down.

I thought this would repeat within the while loop and find the closest toggleSectionDyn div id.  Obviously not.

```
<div class="actions"><a href="#" id="toggleButtonDyn">Add</a></div>
<div id="toggleSectionDyn">Some content</div>
<script>
  $("#toggleButtonDyn").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("#toggleSectionDyn").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: live is deprecated. consider using .on()

you want to use `.live()`

```
 $("#toggleButtonDyn").live('click', (function(){
    $(this).closest("#toggleSectionDyn").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
```

from the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) api

> **The .live() method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM** through the use of event delegation: a handler bound to an ancestor element is responsible for events that are triggered on its descendants. The handler passed to .live() is never bound to an element; instead, .live() binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree.

Now, upon re-reading, I wonder exactly what your asking. You must also make sure each `<div>` must have a unique ID. You may consider you `.next('div')` instead of `.closest()`

Per the discussion in comments, I would use .next('div') look at the modified jsfiddle from yesterdays question http://jsfiddle.net/ycpgD/

also, I would strongly recommend using unique ID's. if they cannot be unique make them classes.

Comment: matchew!  You're back.

Yes--I want to avoid trying to assign unique div IDs.  Since the information I'm trying to display is generated from the database, I think it would be more difficult to generate unique IDs as well.  I think I would then need to have unique jQuery scripts too.

Comment: Oh, hi Andrew! No, you MUST assign unique ids. Its just one of the rules of x/HTML ids must be unique, whereas classes you can reuse.

Comment: but I would suggest then using .next('div'). look at a modified version of yesterdays jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/QGjJZ/ see the how .next() is used. Definitely use that. Also, when you find an answer that suites you don't forget to upvote it and accept it by using the arrows next to the answers see this => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I was getting tripped up using a link instead of a button.  Now is grabs the next div.  Great!

Comment: ah, i see. I'm glad I am able to help you out...again =)

Comment: Thanks!  One last thing.  When I wrap the button in a div, it stops working.  In regards to my last comment, I don't believe it was the link aspect, but the wrapping div.  I tried using two instances of the .next to no avail.  Getting closer though!

Comment: try .parent('div').next('div') think of it like hierarchy. you need to go up, and then next. because there is nothing next

Comment: Brilliant.  And thanks for showing me a bit of the ropes around here.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the div you're after, if you refactor a little. (Maybe I'm missing the issue here, but my solution is pretty straight forward).

http://jsfiddle.net/8nXvX/

```
<div class="actions">
    <div><a href="#">Add</a>
        <p>Some content</p></div>
    <div><a href="#">Add</a>
        <p>Some content</p></div>
</div>

  $(".actions a").click(function(){
    $(this).next('p').slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
```

I suppose it depends where you're generating that `<a>`. If it's a going to hide the entire MySQL result set, or is it going to show/hide each row one at a time?